# CakePHPでNotFoundExceptionをthrowした時のレンダリング処理について

Tags: cakephp, twig

## 環境

- cakephp3.6
- php7.2
- nginx

## 質問

CakePHP3.6を利用しております。
もともとLaravelを使っていたので、テンプレートエンジンが欲しく、
以下のTwigプラグインを使っています。
https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView

しかし、いざエラーページを作成しようと、

- Template/Layout/default.twig
- Template/Error/error400.twig
- Template/Error/error500.twig

を作ったのですが、 `throw new NotFoundException();` しても、nginxのエラーページが表示されてしまいます。
これが何故かわかりません。

ファイルの中身としては、

**Template/Layout/default.twig**

```
OCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {{ Html.charset() | raw }}
    <title>
        エラーページ
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>{{ __('Error') }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {{ _view.fetch('content')|raw }}
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Template/Error/error400.twig**

```
Not Found
```

**Template/Error/error500.twig**

```
Server Error
```

という具合です。

---

あまりにもできなかったため、以下のサイト様を参考にカスタムエクセプション処理を作成しました。
http://moblog.absgexp.net/cakeerr/#i-5

しかし、 `Controller/AppErrorController.php` の `beforeRender` メソッドを徹の確認できるのですが、
結局nginxのエラーページが表示されます。

また、何故かわかりませんが、 `deprecationWarning` 関数を呼び出し、画面にエラーメッセージを表示すると、うまく表示されます。
が、それ本番では流石に使えないので困っております。

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        //「src/Template/Layout/」の下にあるLayoutファイルを参照している
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('error');

        //Templateファイルのあるパスを指定(src/Template/Error/)
        $this->viewBuilder()->setTemplatePath('Error');
        //$this->viewBuilder()->templatePath('Error');
    }
```

どなたかご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ねんのため確認ですがnginxの方の設定で当該のステータスコードについてerror_pageディレクティブが設定されていたりしませんか？バックエンドのステータスコードに応じて内部リダイレクトが発生しているようにもみえます。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。nginx.confを確認したところ、「error_page 404 /404.html;location = /40x.html {}」が書いてありました。。。。これをコメントアウトしてnginxを再起動したのですが、「An Internal Server Error Occurred」という文字だけが表示されるようになりました……（画面は変わりましたが、まだcakeのエラーではありません……）